# Knockout renderTemplate() rendering modes

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js, custom-binding

I'm trying to call `ko.renderTemplate()` in a custom binding.

However I can't find any documentation for it's usage, particularly the rendering mode parameter.

[Knockout.js pro tips – working with templates](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/knockout-js-pro-tips-working-with-templates/)

The site above has a section *"You can render templates directly from your custom bindings"* that briefly describes the parameters to `renderTemplate()`.

**What are the other available options for the rendering mode parameter?**

Additionally, is there any documentation for `renderTemplate()` and the rendering engine options that I may have missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just from looking at the source code of 2.2.0.

The renderMode parameter seems to have two options:

- **replaceNode** - This will replace the entire target node with the output of the template.
- **replaceChildren** - **Default**. This will replace only the children of the target node, leaving the target node intact.

Comment: +1 There is still not enough documentation in the website of Knockout for this useful feature. Ohhhh sorry, there is absolutely no documentation about that :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

You can find ko.renderTemplate() explained pretty well with some examples in [this article](http://aboutcode.net/2012/11/15/twitter-bootstrap-modals-and-knockoutjs.html).

Comment: It is a good article but the template isn't fleshed out enough to get a full understanding and the rest of the code is hidden behind a "spam wall".