# Replace container element when using Knockout component

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, web-component, knockout-components, knockout-templating

Is there a way to configure a [Knockout component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) to *replace* the container element instead of nesting its content inside the container element?

For example, if I have a custom component registered as `my-custom-element` with the following template:

```
<tr>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to use the component like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And have the final product be this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <p>Hello world!</p>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of this: (the way Knockout renders components by default)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <my-custom-element>
            <tr>
                <p>Hello world!</p>
            </tr>
        </my-custom-element>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Based on the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252667/1063392), it seems that this functionality is built into the templating engine, which I'm assuming is also used when rendering component templates.

Is there a way to specify that a component should be rendered with a `renderMode` of `replaceNode`?

I'm aware of the "virtual element" syntax, which allows components to be defined inside an HTML comment:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <!--ko component { name: 'my-custom-element' }--><!--/ko-->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but I really dislike this syntax - writing real code inside a comment feels like a dirty, dirty hack.

Comment: It sounds like [Rendering a named template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) is what you are looking for. Web-component is, generally speaking, a DOM node, shadowing it’s children. It’s not intended to be _replaced_, since the concept itself is ruined in such a case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine the lack of this option could be defended as such, considering the nature of the library (there, I said it), and the developer's team philosophy:

Knockout is a library and unlike other MVC's it does not force you to use a framework-defined way to structure your application. If you consider the template engine in Knockout vs. virtually all other JS templating engines (in Angular, underscore, mustache, etc.), *Knockout comes out as the only one not 'modding' native HTML5 rendering.* All others use a custom tag, be it `<% %>` or `{{ }}` which requires a small JS parser to transform the tags into something meaningful (now KO also has a [Knockout punches](https://github.com/mbest/knockout.punches) plugin which includes the mustache-style tags, and admittedly KO does 'sin' a small bit with `<!-- ko -->` comments). KO instead uses HTML 5 custom elements, comment and attribute tags, completely **"vanilla"**.
For instance, the JS/DOM type of 'object (and real life?) hierarchy' is used: **only parents can ever exerce power on their children**, and so the bound-to element is not replaced, but enlarged with children. For illustration:

```
// we cannot do this in JS
document.getElementById('elem').remove(); //implied .remove(self)
// instead we do this
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
container = elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Subsequently, the preferred way of data-binding with KO, illustrated well by the `foreach` binding, is:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myList">
  <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

The previous snippet being an HTML representation of a JS array, the hierarchy is visible again:

```
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
// we cannot do the following without reference to the array index, 
// which is not held by the object itself,     
// but a meta-property getting meaning relative to the parent
myArr[0].splice(0,1); //remove
```

This leads to your HTML view being a perfect replication of your JS data (and it would be interesting to see someone build a tool that shows the data-bind indentation levels (with `with` and `foreach`) in an HTML document. In some cases however, you need comment tags, so as to not break the lay-out of your HTML, or your css rules (nesting), for example a 'text-only' component (i18n) that is to be injected between text nodes:

```
<p>Some predefined text with
<!-- ko text: 'some variable text' --><!-- /ko -->
and more predefined text</p>
```

Or when you don't want an empty element to take up space when hidden

```
<!-- ko if: !hidden() --><div id="myToggleableDiv"></div><!-- /ko -->
```

And then there are [custom tags](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/04/introduction-to-custom-elements/), which are standardized and a hell of a lot clearer; but unfortunately not a 100% ready yet. Choose `data-bind` first, `<!-- ko -->` second, and `<custom>` third (would be higher if fully implemented). That's how I see it, anyway. As for your specific case, if your component holds a list model, you could do:

```
<table data-bind="{component: {name: 'custom', params {..}}"></table>
```

And include the `tbody` in your VM, else if it is a listitem model, you can use either one of the three 'syntaxes', eg the comment syntax

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: mylist">
    <!-- ko component: {name: 'custom', params: $data} --><!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or decouple your component completely from the requirement of being nested inside a specific parent (table), adhering to the [SOC principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), eg:

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: mylist">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: properties">
      <td data-bind="component: {name: 'custom', params: $data}></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

or with a custom tag:

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: mylist">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: properties">
      <td><custom params= "{data: myData"></custom></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

in that order of preference..

Answer (score 2):

Good News! In Knockout 3.3.0 they just introduced the concept of [Passing markup into components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#passing-markup-into-components). This is done by using the `$componentTemplateNodes` template inside your component.

From the linked example:

```
<template id="my-special-list-template">
    <h3>Here is a special list</h3>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, as: 'myItem' }">
        <li>
            <h4>Here is another one of my special items</h4>
            <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes, data: myItem } --><!-- /ko -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<my-special-list params="items: someArrayOfPeople">
    <!-- Look, I'm putting markup inside a custom element -->
    The person <em data-bind="text: name"></em>
    is <em data-bind="text: age"></em> years old.
</my-special-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comment tags:

https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#note-using-component-without-a-container-element

```
<!-- ko component: {
    name: "message-editor",
    params: { initialText: "Hello, world!", otherParam: 123 }
} -->
<!-- /ko -->
```